# QDrag and Skype issue (win only)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, drag-and-drop, skype

I am writing a little file/archives explorer and got an issue with interaction between qt-based app and Skype chat window on Windows platform only.

When I try to drag-drop file (provided by QDrag with file-urls mime data) from my app to skype chat window, file is sent twice. The same I’ve got when tried to modify one of Qt drag-drop examples.

Skype version is 5.10.0.116. Bug is reproducible on Qt versions 4.7.3, 4.8.1, 4.8.3.

**EDIT:**

Have tried drag-drop interactions between several apps

- My app -> Explorer = ok
- My app -> Notepad++ = ok (displays content of file only in one tab)
- My app -> WinRar = ok (creates archive with
  only one file)
- My app -> TotalCommander = ok
- My app -> ICQ = ok (only    one file is    sent)
- My app -> Clementine (Qt based music player) = ok    (only one file
  is added to playlist)
- Explorer -> Skype = ok

**But**

- My app -> Skype - file is sent twice
- Clementine -> Skype - file is sent twice

**EDIT2:**

Also, qt-created mime data differs from created by explorer.

Qt:

- 0 "text/uri-list" "file:///C:/Users/user/Pictures/myfile.ext"
- 1 "application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="UniformResourceLocatorW""
  "..." (I've replaced QByteArray contents with ellipsis)

Explorer:

- 0 "application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Shell IDList Array"" "..."
- 1 "application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="UsingDefaultDragImage""
  "..."
- 2 "application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragImageBits"" "..."
- 3 "application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragContext"" "..."
- 4 "application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragSourceHelperFlags""
  "..."
- 5 "application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="InShellDragLoop"" "..."
- 6 "text/uri-list" "file:///C:/Users/user/Pictures/myfile.ext"

Comment: One idea is: Create a small helper app, which queries the available data inside a drop element. And see which data a drag from explorer provides and check what your application provides. I would say its a bug in skype, not correctly handling your given mime type or types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, it’s not a problem if Qt, it’s wrong mime data processing on Skype side. Along with “text/uri-list”, Qt provides “UniformResourceLocatorW” value with the same data (i cant deny it, it is added a much deeper, than Qt user can get). And Skype processes both values – “text/uri-list” and “UniformResourceLocatorW”, causing sending the same file twice.